# BERT multilingual model - For classification

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, lstm, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I am trying to build multilingual classification model with BERT.

I'm using a feature-based approach (concatenating the features from top-4 hidden layers) and building a CNN classifier on top of that.

After that I'm using different language (say chinese) from the same domain for testing, but accuracy for these languages is near zero.

I am not sure that I understand paper well, so here is my question:

Is it possible to fine-tune BERT multilingual model on one language
(e.g. English) or use feature-based approach to extract the features and build classifer, and after that use this model for different languages (other
languages from the list of supported languages in documentation of
BERT)?

Also, is my hypothesis, "regarding BERT that it maps I think that it's embedding layer maps words from different languages with same context to similar clusters", correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but as far as I know, BERT does not explicitly do it (you get some English names in Chinese texts and thus you may predict Chinese tokens from English and have them in single space,but it seems that it's not enough). You get byte-pair encodings as features and they will be completely different for English and Chinese. Your approach may work for some close languages (French and English) to some (very limited) extent. You may check something like https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE which does what you expect. You may train your classifier on top of frozen MUSE embeddings.

Comment: @DenisGordeev Thanks for the answers and the link about MUSE

Comment: @DenisGordeev Here FB has provided an approach to get language agnostic features (LASER) https://code.fb.com/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.10464.pdf Is that similar to what MUSE is doing? Did you have any experience with LASER, if yes then which one do you think performs better MUSE or LASER?

Comment: Don't chase the latest shiny model... Understand your problem, all you need is a classifier, have you tried a simple naive bayes maximum likelihood baseline? Have you tried a normal multi-layered feed-forward network?

Comment: @Deeplearnbeginner I have no experience with LASER but it seems from their descriptions that it would be even easier to use it for your purpose (it has more languages). I would really try LASER first.

Comment: @alvas Yes I tried Logistic Regression, it is giving descent performance even though the data is less, after analysis we found that the edge cases like wherever context based understanding is required for classification there logistic regression is failing so I wanted to experiment whether Contextual Embedding based models might do well and hopefully they should do better than logistic regression.

Comment: Ngram captures context, have you tried something like https://github.com/alvations/bayesline-DSL/blob/master/dsl-2019.py